# how to get only one record based on column value in oracle join

Tags: sql, oracle, select

[image]

I need to get only one record for column value 1 while joining `table1`, Can some one please tell me is this achievable in Oracle?

Currently I have

```
join (select * from table2 where column1='1') tab2result
on table1.column1 = tab2result.column1.
```

While joining I need only the first record for distinct `column1` values.

Comment: How do you define 'first'? Random choice, by given order on column 2, or by some other criteria?

Comment: select * from table1
left join (select * from table2 where column1='criteria') results
on table1.column1 = results.column;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically,

```
Select t1.column1
     , t1.column2
     , t2first.column2
  From table t1
  Join (
           Select row_number() over (partition by t2.column1 order by t2.column2) AS rn
                , t2.column1
                , t2.column2
             from table t2
       ) t2first on ( t2first.column1 = t1.column1 )
 where t2first.rn = 1
     ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the aggregate `max` (or `min`, for that matter) function in a subquery:

```
SELECT t1.colum1, t1.column2, t2.column1, t2.column2
FROM   table1 t1
JOIN   (SELECT   column1, MAX(column2) AS column2
        FROM     table2
        GROUP BY column1) t2 ON t1.column1 = t2.column1
```